# Can we retrieve the applications currently running in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Anyone  Please  tell me any API/otherway to retrieve the applications currently running in windows phone 7.

in android and iPhone getting that what about in windows phone 7.please tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Task Manager details in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721322/how-to-get-task-manager-details-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Asking the same question 3 different ways is unlikely to get you a different answer to the one you originally got.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine the currently running programs, and strictly speaking, there is only ever one that is running, [as per the WP7.1 lifecycle](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/a-windows-phone-7-1-mango-mvvm-tombstoning-example/) (apart from agents). Windows Phone 7 has a deliberately restrictive API in this respect.