# How to get Task Manager details in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

[image]

How to get above information programatically in wp7?.please tell me idea on this....

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for that, sorry. Applications in Windows Phone 7 are built in a way which forbids you to get this kind of system level information.